# Automatic updating of a Chrome extension doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome-extension, auto-update

I'm trying to implement the automatic update feature of my [Chrome extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/3298/cv-pls-helper-chrome-extension). But for some reason it doesn't work. I have an `updates.xml` file hosted on GitHub and I see it gets downloaded (the download counter shows this). But the [latest version](https://github.com/downloads/PeeHaa/cv-pls/cv-pls.0.14.0.crx) of the extension is never downloaded.

My `manifest.json` looks like:

```
"version": "0.14.0",
"update_url": "https://github.com/downloads/PeeHaa/cv-pls/updates.xml",
```

And my `updates.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
  <app appid='bcbifciedokdgkokbbfippkbecnkpclj'>
    <updatecheck codebase='https://github.com/downloads/PeeHaa/cv-pls/cv-pls.0.14.0.crx' version='0.14.0' />
  </app>
</gupdate>
```

I've checked and double-checked the `appid` and the download URL and they both are correct.

Does anybody have any idea what's going wrong here? Does it have something to do with the fact it is hosted on GitHub?

Comment: Have autoupdates work in the past with the same setup?

Comment: @abraham nopez. never worked.

Comment: Related: [How to host a chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10737123/367456)

Answer (score 3):

I've tried this approach before and failed as well. The update.xml file was downloaded correctly, but the newest version of my app wouldn't install.

I found out it doesn't work because github doesn't provide the correct header. If you look at the [hosting documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/hosting.html), the content-type header should be "application/x-chrome-extension".

I just wrote a simple script in php to serve the file for me:

```
<?php
$file = "";
header("Content-type: application/x-chrome-extension");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='extension.crx'");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
echo readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: I just ran `curl -v --head http://cloud.github.com/downloads/PeeHaa/cv-pls/cv-pls.0.14.0.crx` and the header `Content-Type: application/x-chrome-extension` is present int the response.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like both the update.xml and the crx URLs redirect from `https://github.com` to `https://cloud.github.com`. This is the only reason I can see that would cause the update to fail. Try updating the update.xml codebase URL to include `cloud`.

Comment: Still [doesn't work](https://github.com/PeeHaa/cv-pls/downloads). I see that my latest updates.xml is downloaded multiple times, but I don't see any downloads of the extension itself :(

Comment: I'm going to do some testing this weekend because it looks like it should work. I know I've used Gists for update.xml before and it worked fine. Ping me on Sunday if I don't post an update.