# How to host a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to host my chrome extension on my shared hosting with PHP.

I know that my server must use appropriates HTTP headers: [code.google.com/chrome/extensions/hosting.html](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/hosting.html)

But, how to set my server to send these headers in addiction to .crx file ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are on a shared hosting and can't change server configuration, use PHP:

```
<?php
$file = 'extension.crx';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/x-chrome-extension');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

This will force file (specified by `$file` variable) download with customized headers.

Comment: This is correct from a technical point of view but doesn't work any more in newer versions of Chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what web server are you using, but for Apache you can do the following:

1. vi `/path/to/your/httpd/conf/mime.types`
2. Add this line: `application/x-chrome-extension crx` at the end of the file
3. Restart your webserver: `killall -HUP httpd`

Or you can try adding this line to your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/x-chrome-extension crx
```

And it should work!

Comment: I am using a shared hosting, so I can't edit Apache settings. Could I do this in PHP ?

Comment: I've found something. You can try add these to your .htaccess: AddType application/x-chrome-extension crx